# Why do we use the definite article in the phrase "the clocks go back"?

Tags: phrases

British Summer Time, or Daylight Saving Time, ends this weekend. Why do we say ***the*** clocks go back? As we are referring to clocks in general shouldn't it just be "clocks go back"?

Comment: Because *all* the clocks go back. It is collective. Another example: "People go the beach in summer", vs "The people voted to leave EU."

Comment: I think *clocks go back* or *clocks are set back* work as well without the article.

Comment: Here, using 'the'  or the (null, Ø2, I think) article is largely a style choice. Though my choices would be identical to that in the piece below: 'When do the clocks go back in autumn 2022? ... ... ... Clocks go forward by one hour at 1am on the last Sunday in March to mark the beginning of BST....'  [[Ellie Kemp; Manchester Evening News; Oct 2022](https://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/news/uk-news/clocks-go-back-autumn-2022-25224593)]

Comment: Why do we use the definite article in the phrase _the wrong number_? Is there only one?

Comment: I think it just sounds more natural to add "the"; without it, "clocks" sounds indefinite - "clocks go back" could refer to some clocks. "The" also emphasises it's a particular event you need to pay attention to, rather than just a case of some clocks running slowly. As mentioned, neither is wrong, but you can speculate why psychologically one version sounds better.

Comment: I don't think we commonly say *the clocks go back* in American English.

Comment: It's much the same reason as in "Apart from man, **the lion** is the primary predator in Africa." I'm sure there is more than one lion on the continent. In fact, searching for that idea here I've found a duplicate question which answers this.